# ASP.NET C# - Retrieving HTML Button from Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I have a repeater containing, amongst others, two buttons.  One of the buttons is an ASP.NET button whilst the other is of the type "input type="button"".

Now, in my code-behind, I want to retrieve both buttons from the repeater to either hide them or show them.  I have successfully hidden the ASP.NET button however I do not know how to retrieve the other button.

Here is some code in ASP.NET:

```
<input type="button" name="ButtonEditUpdate" runat="server" value="Edit Update" class="ButtonEditUpdate" />
<asp:Button ID="ButtonDeleteUpdate" CssClass="ButtonDeleteUpdate" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete Update" />
```

Here is the code-behind:

```
protected void RepeaterUpdates_ItemBinding(object source, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
    TextBox Update_ID = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBoxUpdateID_Repeater");
    //Button Edit_Update = (Button)item.FindControl("ButtonEditUpdate");
    Button Delete_Update = (Button)item.FindControl("ButtonDeleteUpdate");

    if (Social_ID == String.Empty)
    {
        //Edit_Update.Visible = false;
        Delete_Update.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

How can I retrieve the HTML button and hide it since it is NOT an ASP.NET button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you cannot *straightly* retrieve a plain-old HTML button because ASP.NET considers that as part of the text markup. Fortunately, you already added `runat="server"` that makes your button a server control.

The easiest way is to use an `HtmlButton` control. But in your markup you need the `id` attribute

```
<input type="button" name="ButtonEditUpdate" runat="server" value="Edit Update" class="ButtonEditUpdate" id="ButtonEditUpdate" />
```

Then in the code behind

```
//Button Edit_Update = (Button)item.FindControl("ButtonEditUpdate");
HtmlButton Delete_Update = (HtmlButton)item.FindControl("ButtonEditUpdate");
```

Answer (score 2):

That button is a HTML control and will be of type `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton`

```
 System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton button = item.FindControl("ButtonEditUpdate") as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton;
 if(button!=null)
      button.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to set the visibility you shouldn't need to cast it.

```
 var myButton = e.Item.FindControl("ButtonEditUpdate");
 if(myButton != null)
    myButton.Visible = false;
```

EDIT: you should give your button an ID.